# фиксация блока по координате вертикали

Tags: javascript, css, css3

У меня на сайте присутствует боковое меню которое должно фиксироваться при вертикальном скроллинге страницы, я решил эту проблему следующим образом:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
$('#menu').css({
    'top': $(this).scrollTop()
});});
```

Но проблема в том что при таком подходе страница автоматически удлиняется вниз, кода пользователь проскроллит до самого низа страницы, подскажите что делать?

Comment: "по координате X" - по координате Y?

Comment: Ошибся немного) В общем по вертикали

Comment: а position:fixed уже не в моде?

Comment: но position: fixed фиксирует по горизонтали, а этого мне не нужно)

Comment: @DrAmx, там что, горизонтальный скролл?

Comment: @Cheg, я добавил в ответ возможность скролл показать. Видимо, он такое хочет. Впрочем, если меню двигаться по вертикали не должно, то это делается через absolute.

Comment: @DrAmx что значит "фиксирует по горизонтали"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если это возможно, рекомендую использовать css `position: sticky`.
[Поддерживается в](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) Edge 16+, FF 32+, Chrome 56+, Safari 8+.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

img, aside {
  float: left;
  width: 8em;
}

aside {
  margin-top: 8px;
  clear: left;
  background: silver;

  -webkit-position: sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

aside a {
  display: block;
}

main {
  margin-left: 9em;
}

p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#hscroll {
  display: none;
}

#hscroll:checked ~ main {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type=checkbox id=hscroll>

<img src=//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=256&d=identicon&r=PG>

<aside>
  <label for=hscroll>Show/hide scroll</label>
  <a>Menu 1</a>
  <a>Menu 2</a>
  <a>Menu 3</a>
  <a>Menu 4</a>
  <a>Menu 5</a>
  <a>Menu 6</a>
  <a>Menu 7</a>
  <a>Menu 8</a>
  <a>Menu 9</a>
</aside>

<main>
  <p>У меня на сайте присутствует боковое меню которое должно фиксироваться при вертикальном скроллинге страницы, я решил эту проблему следующим образом: $(window).scroll(function(){ $('#menu').css({     'top': $(this).scrollTop() });}); Но проблема в том что при таком подходе страница автоматически удлиняется вниз, кода пользователь проскроллит до самого низа страницы, подскажите что делать?</p>
  <p>У меня на сайте присутствует боковое меню которое должно фиксироваться при вертикальном скроллинге страницы, я решил эту проблему следующим образом: $(window).scroll(function(){ $('#menu').css({     'top': $(this).scrollTop() });}); Но проблема в том что при таком подходе страница автоматически удлиняется вниз, кода пользователь проскроллит до самого низа страницы, подскажите что делать?</p>
  <p>У меня на сайте присутствует боковое меню которое должно фиксироваться при вертикальном скроллинге страницы, я решил эту проблему следующим образом: $(window).scroll(function(){ $('#menu').css({     'top': $(this).scrollTop() });}); Но проблема в том что при таком подходе страница автоматически удлиняется вниз, кода пользователь проскроллит до самого низа страницы, подскажите что делать?</p>
  <p>У меня на сайте присутствует боковое меню которое должно фиксироваться при вертикальном скроллинге страницы, я решил эту проблему следующим образом: $(window).scroll(function(){ $('#menu').css({     'top': $(this).scrollTop() });}); Но проблема в том что при таком подходе страница автоматически удлиняется вниз, кода пользователь проскроллит до самого низа страницы, подскажите что делать?</p>
  <p>У меня на сайте присутствует боковое меню которое должно фиксироваться при вертикальном скроллинге страницы, я решил эту проблему следующим образом: $(window).scroll(function(){ $('#menu').css({     'top': $(this).scrollTop() });}); Но проблема в том что при таком подходе страница автоматически удлиняется вниз, кода пользователь проскроллит до самого низа страницы, подскажите что делать?</p>
  <p>У меня на сайте присутствует боковое меню которое должно фиксироваться при вертикальном скроллинге страницы, я решил эту проблему следующим образом: $(window).scroll(function(){ $('#menu').css({     'top': $(this).scrollTop() });}); Но проблема в том что при таком подходе страница автоматически удлиняется вниз, кода пользователь проскроллит до самого низа страницы, подскажите что делать?</p>
  <p>У меня на сайте присутствует боковое меню которое должно фиксироваться при вертикальном скроллинге страницы, я решил эту проблему следующим образом: $(window).scroll(function(){ $('#menu').css({     'top': $(this).scrollTop() });}); Но проблема в том что при таком подходе страница автоматически удлиняется вниз, кода пользователь проскроллит до самого низа страницы, подскажите что делать?</p>
</main>
```